# Showing 2D array with one element at the time

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I have a 2 dimensional array filled with 0s and 1s. I have to display that array in way that:
- 0s are always shown
- 1s are shown one at the time.

It suppose to look like a maze where 0 is a wall and 1 is a current position.
How can I do that in c++?

EDIT:
I came up with a solution but maybe there is simpler one. What if I'd create copy of my _array and copy 0s and blank spaces instead of 1s to it. Then in loop I'd assign one of _array "1" to second array then display whole array and then make swap 1 back with blank space?

EDIT2:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    file();
    int k=0,l=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num_rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<num_chars;j++)
        {
            if(_array[i][j] == 1)
            {
                k=i;
                l=j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<num_rows;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<num_chars;j++)
            {
                if(_array[i][j] == 0) printf("%d",_array[i][j]);
                else if(_array[i][j]==1)
                {
                    if(k==i && l==j)
                    {
                        printf("1");                

                    }
                    else printf(" ");

                }               
                l++;
                if(l>num_chars) break;
            }
            k++;
            l=0;
            printf("\n");               
        }
        k=0;
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote something like that but still i don't know how to clear screen in right moment. Function file() reads from file to 2D array.

Comment: (1) you should probably add the homework tag, and (2) you should show us your attempt thus far so people can critique it and give you ideas on how to progress, and (3) nice cut the rope picture :)

Comment: Actually it's not homework because i'm not a student anymore :) I just want to learn c++ on my own.

Comment: Do you want to display a 1 traveling through a maze of zeroes? Did I understand that right?

Comment: I'm guessing he wants the current path from start to the current position to be covered in 1's.  The ones would move down all of the paths showing it trying to solve it, and backing up as it runs into walls.  Basically displaying the progress of a recursive search algorithm.  Am I right? We had to do something back in college like that :)

Comment: Well, the harder part is generating the maze in the first place.  Check this out: http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/06/07/maze-generator/ after you get that right, you can use a recursive search algorithm to solve it.  I'd use a graphical display instead of text to draw the maze though - if you're really going to draw it to console repeatedly I think you'll be sadly dissapointed at the output you get trying to print a maze repeatedly trying to chase a recursive search algorithms output.  PS: recursive search probably isn't the right word, but its some form of backtracking path finder

Comment: No no no :) I don't want to do any maze solving algorithm. I just want to do something like that: I have array 3x3:
when i run program i want too see 0s and first found "1", rest of 1s will be shown as blank space. In next iteration i want to see 0s like before but not first fund "1" but second one, and rest would be blank spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want something like that

```
000000
0    0
0000 0
0 1  0
0 0000
000000
```

You could print a `0` whenever it occurs and a blank space if not. To handle the current position you could use two additional variables like `posX`, `posY`. Now everytime you find a `1` in your array you check `if (j == posX && i = posY)` and print `1` if so...

As you just need to visualize the maze at different possible positions I'd propose a simple display function. `DisplayMaze(int x, int y)` is printing the maze in the required format to the screen. If `_array[y][x] == 1` there is also printed a single `1`...

```
void DisplayMaze(int x, int y)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < num_rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < num_chars; col++)
        {
            if (_array[row][col] == 0)
                std::cout << "0 ";
            else if (row == y && col == x)
                std::cout << "1 ";
            else
                std::cout << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In order to display all possible positions you have to iterate over all of them and check if the current position is marked with `1` in the array (otherwise displaying would't make sense)

```
for (int y = 0; y < num_rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < num_chars; x++)
    {
        if (_array[y][x] == 1)
        {
            DisplayMaze(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should look like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1       0
0 0 0 0   0
0         0
0   0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0
0   1     0
0 0 0 0   0
0         0
0   0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0
0     1   0
0 0 0 0   0
0         0
0   0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0
0       1 0
0 0 0 0   0
0         0
0   0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0
0         0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0         0
0   0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

...

However, i'd recommend a more C++ like approach as a maze could be implemented as a class. This class could bring it's own display-method and would encapsulate the internal data. It could basically look like:

```
class Maze
{
public:
    // generate empty maze with given size
    Maze(int width, int height);

    // destructor
    ~Maze();

    // print maze if the given position is marked with 1
    void printPosition(int x, int y) const;

    // takes a cstring as input to initialize the maze from
    Maze& operator<<(const char* input);

    // returns true if the given position is marked with 1
    bool isValidPosition(int x, int y) const;

private:
    // this is the actual representation of the maze
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > grid_;
};
```

it would be used as followes:

```
Maze myMaze(num_chars, num_rows);
myMaze << "000000"
    "011110"
    "000010"
    "011110"
    "010000"
    "000000";

for (int y = 0; y < num_rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < num_chars; x++)
    {
        if (myMaze.isValidPosition(x,y))
        {
            myMaze.printPosition(x,y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what do you say to my suggestion? :-)

Comment: I tried do something like that but as you can see it doesn't run as i want it to. Maybe using only while(1) loop and manually control all the counters will do the trick?

Comment: As i said before i don't want to write maze solving algorithm. I just want to display 2D array in way that 0 is always visible and only one "1" is visible at the time.

Comment: Hmm, ok but is it important wich `1` is displayed? Or is it important to have every `1` beeing displayed in tha maze once at all?

Comment: Actually it is. Why? Because I'm learning c++ and that is the problem i'd like to solve. It's not any homework or anything like that. I just thought that it'd be fun to do that but i was a little bit overwhelmed in progress.

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't mean to offend you ;-) i'll update my answer later

Comment: No problem. Thank you that you want to help me. I know that is stupid problem but i really want to solve this.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I'll definitely try it.

Comment: Hi Divh, if my answer helped you (of course only then), you might want to accept it. I've spent a lot of time figuring out how to help you

Answer (score 0):

hire you go**[**solved**]**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x,y;
cin>>x>>y;
char map[x][y];
memset(map, 'a', sizeof(map));
int y_pos = 0;
for (int x_pos = 0; x_pos < x * y; x_pos++){
    if (x_pos == x){
       x_pos = 0;
       y_pos = y_pos + 1;
       cout<<endl;
       }
    if (y_pos == y){
       system("pause");
       return 0;       
       }
    cout<<map[x_pos][y_pos];
    }
```